# IF ELSE Statement in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

I made an Access Log menu. The point I make it is that I can see a users activity. I have some difficulties in displaying String message in menu table after using `if else` with `PreparedStatement` in jsp. Before I put the code below, first I need to explain the basics. I have a button in Access Log page named `BtnReport`. And when clicking the menu page, it will display as Page View in Access Log table, and when pressing BtnReport, it will display that the page was successfully displayed.

Click here to see the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEI4v.png)

And finally, the code:

```
<%
String serverIP = request.getRemoteAddr();
            String sqllog = "INSERT INTO accesslog (userid,hostip,status,webflag,logtype,action) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                            PreparedStatement pst=cn.prepareStatement(sqllog);
                            pst.setString(1,(String) session.getAttribute("user"));
                            pst.setString(2,serverIP);
                            pst.setString(3,"-");
                            pst.setInt(4,1);
                            pst.setString(5,"WEB_ADMIN_"+vMenuGroup+"-"+vMenuTitle);
                            if (request.getParameter("BtnReport")==null)
                                    pst.setString(6,"Page View");
                            else 
                                    pst.setString(6,"Report");
                                    pst.setString(3,"success");
                          pst.executeUpdate();
                          pst.close();  %>
```

When a user clicks the Report button, I want the String message set as "Success" and the Page View only with "-". Can anyone help me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are not using brackets:

```
else {//missing
     pst.setString(6,"Report");
     pst.setString(3,"success"); //without brackets, this line does not falls under else block
}//missing
```

Comment: Arvid is right. The if statement is okay because it only has one line of code running after it. Anything more than one will require brackets.

Comment: @Arvind I already tried it before, and it still didn't work.. It still show Page View status as "success".

Comment: @bmarkham I understand the requirement for multiple statement, before posting this question, I already tried using brackets, and it still didn't work.. I'm still figuring out what I'm missing here..

Comment: So does it just do nothing?

Comment: @bmarkham Finally it was solved.. I'm confused about the pst.set part (should it be in sequence or not)..

I moved it in if statement, so if and else have two lines, using brackets as suggested.. Thanks a lot!